How to apply a mask in a GStreamer?
I'm trying to apply a mask in GStreamer but I can't find much documentation on this specific use case. The idea is that I have a mask file and I want to apply it on an image/stream. I believe I could use the videomixer but I'm not sure if that's the right way to do it. I am using GStreamer in C++. Also I heard of compositor plugin not sure if it can be useful.

Did you know or See cairooverlay ?
